# Android studio debug-specific AndroidManifest.xml for ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATIONS

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, mocking, manifest

While importing project from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio` it has reported following error:
[image]

What may cause the problem? Any idea how to deal with this?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

> What may cause the problem?

Apparently, you have that `<uses-permission>` element in a manifest that would be used for a production app, and they now have a Lint rule to block that.

> Any idea how to deal with this?

Create a `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` file, with a root `<manifest>` element holding onto your `<uses-permission>` element, and remove that `<uses-permission>` element from where you are getting the error (presumably `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`).

Answer (score 0):

This lint error currently does limit use of the permission to debug specific manifests in AndroidStudio 1.0.+ but the lint guidelines are being adjusted to allow the permission to also work in test specific manifests [in an up coming version](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/122171/1) of AndroidStudio.